# Why weren't CP9 at the battle in Marineford Arc?

Tags: one-piece

I'm just curious as to why weren't the CP9 members present at marine ford during the Whitebeard war.
They are also a part of marines and are even the strongest Soru users so is there any specific reason as to why they weren't there?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason is simple: they are no longer under the World Government, and have been declared as fugitives. The side story *CP9's Independent Report* covers what the CP9 members did after the Enies Lobby arc. This side story was carried as a mini-series on cover pages of One Piece manga chapters 491 to 528.

Bruno used his Air Door to save the CP9 members from the Buster Call. On returning to the destroyed island after the Marine attack, Bruno and Jabra notice the Government forces are looking for them. Suspecting that Spandam plans to capture them, they flee the island to St. Poplar.

Rob Lucci sustained severe injuries in the fight against Luffy, so the other CP9 members work in St. Poplar to pay for his treatment. After Lucci's treatment, they defeat the Candy Pirates who attacked St. Poplar, and return to their hometown.

In the meantime, Spandam presumably blamed them for the Enies Lobby debacle and got them declared as fugitives. He sent Marine pursuers, led by Captain Very Good, to capture them. CP9 defeat the pursuers and set sail to high seas, after Rob Lucci tells Spandam over a Den Den Mushi that they would return.

Comment: and why are they (Spandam & Lucci ) working together as CP 0 then ? i doubt they will be buddy-buddy after Enies Lobby fiasco

Comment: @NamikazeSheena I agree, they are probably working together for some selfish purposes (like Crocodile joined Luffy temporarily during Marineford Arc), or maybe Spandam has "changed" (like Helmeppo working with Coby under Garp). It hasn't been revealed yet, but I would expect Oda to carry another side-story if they will play any important role in future.

Comment: @MaskedMan or someone stronger put them on leash (Like how crocodile controlling Baroque Works)